# Unique UUIDs from multiple processes on same machine

Tags: python, uuid

To tag the data we create, I'm considering using uuids.  Security is not an issue, so I was going to use version 1 (date-and-mac-address-based).  The only concern is that each user may be creating multiple data files at once from different processes with multiple threads.  Assuming Python's uuid library is thread-safe (though it doesn't look it), that still leaves the multiple process issue.  I'm considering suffixing the uuid with a dash and the process number.

Since our group has little experience with uuids, are there any issues I need to keep in mind?  How is the multiple process issue usually handled?

Comment: The thread-unsafe part of Python 2.5's `uuid.uuid1()` is when it compares the current current timestamp to the previous timestamp.  Without a lock, two processes can end up comparing against the same globally saved timestamp.  (That's what it looks like to my untrained eyes.)

Comment: I was hoping for an answer the described more of the conventions in designing a uuid.  In particular I was worried there was a good reason not to use the straight process id.  But, lacking that, I'll accept wcoenen's answer.  He has a good point, but I don't think it's relevant for my particular circumstances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [uuid4](http://docs.python.org/library/uuid.html#uuid.uuid4) for completely random UUIDs. There is no need to worry about collisions.

**edit in response to comment**: In my experience, redundant data leads to inconsistencies sooner or later. There is a reason that avoiding redundancy is a dogma of relational database design.

So don't use the UUID as a "redundancy backup" for the actual "originating computer" and "timestamp" data. Either use it as a pure unique ID carrying no other information, or don't use it at all.

Comment: I would prefer to have the (weak) traceability of uuid1.  That metadata (creation time, computer) should be written into the files themselves, but like most coding standards, there's no guarantee.

Comment: Trust me, we have plenty of inconsistencies now, and we ain't writing nearly enough.  I'd rather have it as a backup and never use it, than rely on all our programs to do the right thing.  The latter is an impossibility.  This at least give me a small chance when someone screws up the data.  (I don't mean to use it programmatically, just every now and then when we need to track our mistakes.)  If I was going to use it regularly, I'd use something easier to read than a uuid.